# Multiple Modal Triggers

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to utilize multiple triggers on a page, to bring up a specific modal each time.  The problem I'm having is that it only bring up the last modal i've used. I have set up different names for the modals and buttons, however, the same modal continues to popup, regardless of which button I select and it's always the last one I developed. Below is the html and script I am using for both, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="container-row-two">
    <div class="container-Asset">
        <button class="btn-Asset" id="myBtn-Asset">
        <img class="image-icon" src="Asset.png" alt=""><p>Asset</p>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="container-Pros">
        <button class="btn-Pros" id="myBtn-Pros">
        <img class="image-icon" src="Pros.png" alt=""><p>Pros</p>
        </button>
    </div>
    </div>

        <!-- This is the Asset MODAL section -->
        <div class="Asset-Modal">
        <div id="myModal-Asset" class="modal-Asset">

        <!-- Modal Design  -->
        <div class="modal-content-Asset">
        <span class="close-Asset">&times;</span>
        <img class="image-icon-Asset" src="Asset.png" alt="Asset"><p>Asset</p></span>
        <div class="modal-content-Asset-info">
        </div>
        </div>

        <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal-Asset");
        
        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn-Asset");
        
        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close-Asset")[0];
        
        // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
        btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        }
        
        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        
        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        }
        </script>
      </div>

        <!-- This is the Pros MODAL section -->
        <div class="Pros-Modal">
        <div id="myModal-Pros" class="modal-Pros">

        <!-- Modal Design  -->
        <div class="modal-content-Pros">
        <span class="close-Pros">&times;</span>
        <img class="image-icon-Pros" src="Pros.png" alt="Asset"><p>Pros</p></span>
        <div class="modal-content-Pros-info">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal-Pros");
        
        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn-Pros");
        
        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close-Pros")[0];
        
        // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
        btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        }
        
        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        
        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need named variable diffrent from another, because when the page rendered and you have same name variable, the value of the variable will have the last one

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal-Asset");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn-Asset");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close-Asset")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Get the modal
var modal2 = document.getElementById("myModal-Pros");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn-Pros");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close-Pros")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal2) {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-row-two">
    <div class="container-Asset">
        <button class="btn-Asset" id="myBtn-Asset">
            <img class="image-icon" src="Asset.png" alt=""><p>Asset</p>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="container-Pros">
        <button class="btn-Pros" id="myBtn-Pros">
            <img class="image-icon" src="Pros.png" alt=""><p>Pros</p>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- This is the Asset MODAL section -->
<div class="Asset-Modal">
    <div id="myModal-Asset" class="modal-Asset">

        <!-- Modal Design  -->
        <div class="modal-content-Asset">
            <span class="close-Asset">&times;</span>
            <span><img class="image-icon-Asset" src="Asset.png" alt="Asset"><p>Asset</p></span>
            <div class="modal-content-Asset-info"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- This is the Pros MODAL section -->
<div class="Pros-Modal">
    <div id="myModal-Pros" class="modal-Pros">

    <!-- Modal Design  -->
    <div class="modal-content-Pros">
        <span class="close-Pros">&times;</span>
        <span><img class="image-icon-Pros" src="Pros.png" alt="Asset"><p>Pros</p></span>
        <div class="modal-content-Pros-info"> </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: maybe you can give this asnwer to accepted